# plotting median of the points in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question (I am new to R and already spend couple hours looking for the code) in plotting median for the following. I hope someone can help me!

```
TYPE(time)      DV
    0             1
    1             2 
    2             4 
    5             6
    7             7
    0             1
    1             2  
    2             3 
    5             6
    7             7
    1             2 
    2             4 
    5             6
    7             7
    0             1
    1             2  
    2             5 
    5             7
    7             8
    0             1 
    1             1 
    2             4 
    5             6
    7             7
    0             1
    1             2  
    2             3 
    5             6
    7             7
```

I wish to plot both the median and line that goes through the median of y-axis (in this case DV) using GGplot2. I have only constructed the code for the first points and hope to add on the median. THANKS!!!

```
library(ggplus)
gg1 <- ggplot(dataplot) +
  geom_point(aes(x=TYPE, y=DV)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the median of `DV` for each type firstly, and then use `geom_segment` to draw the line in the plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(TYPE) %>% mutate(med = median(DV))

gg1 <- ggplot(df1) +
       geom_point(aes(x=TYPE, y=DV)) + 
       geom_segment(aes(x = TYPE-0.5, xend = TYPE+0.5, y = med, yend = med))
```

[image]

As a side note, generally `geom_boxplot()` is more often used when a quantile distribution of the variable is desired, with which you can do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = TYPE, y = DV, group = TYPE)) + geom_point() + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

The position of median is the same as we draw manually above.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am unfamiliar with dplyr. When I ran 'code' df1 <- df %>% group_by(TYPE) %>% mutate(med = median(DV))" '/code' , it gave me Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"   Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Not very sure. Try to detach and reattach your dplyr package, sometimes, there are functions overriding problems when other packages are loaded after `dplyr`.

Comment: I tried deattaching and reattaching; it doesn't work T_T. Is there another method in doing so?

Comment: There is a base R method you can try. `df$med = ave(df$DV, df$TYPE, FUN=median)`. Notice here is just `df`, no `df1` anymore.